# Azure Devops Show all repositories from the project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, repository, azure-repos

I have a project "ABC" in the AzureDevops. I have couple of repositories created inside this project. I would like to have a view/dashboard which will show all repositories as a list. Every repository of this list is a link/button which when clicked, redirects me to the Repo page, where I can see the commits, branches, pull requests etc. Currently the "Summary" (Overview) page of the "ABC" project does not show anything:

[image]

How can I see all repositories? Can I include a list of repositories on the Summary/Overview Page?
I was thinking if I click the "Repos" button from the left pane:
[image]
I might see the list but instead, I am being forwarded to a first repository from the Project.

Answer (score 1):

The repositories overview can be found from in the Project's settings pages an can also be accessed from the currently selected repository by clicking the <kbd>⚙️ Manage repositories</kbd> option in the repo selector.

Url:

- `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_settings/repositories`

[image]

Comment: The link which you posted is _not_ what I was looking for. Because althout I see a list of repositories, when I click on one of them it does not rediirect me to the repo page, where I can see the commits , branches, pull requests. Instead it redirects me to settings of this repo. Besides that  do you know if I could include this list of repositories to the "Overview" /"Summary" View of the whole project? Navigating to "Settings" and then to "Repositories" is totaly unintuitive for me. –

Answer (score 1):

I have created a feature request for this funcionality: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Devops-Show-all-repositories-from/10502088 If anyone is interested in that please up vote:)

Answer (score 0):

I found two extensions in the Marketplace that meets your needs.

The first is the [Git repository list](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CrazySolutions.git-repository-list).

[image]

You can also check the repo list in the organization page and select **My repositories**.

[image]

The second one is [repo-board](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ovantol.repo-board).

[image]

You can choose one of the above.

Comment: They look very interesting. I will check them out.

Comment: Hi @Miao you are very correct, thanks for reminder. I tried to use those extensions but unfortunately when I try to add it  need to post request to admin. : "Admin privileges are required to acquire this extension. You can submit a request to your organization’s admin." I  am not allowed to do this requests in my organisation unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, to install extensions, you must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group.

Comment: Hi @fascynacja, I find a new way to check the repo list. Please check the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, In my portal I do not see the tab "my repositories"

Comment: @fascynacja, oh, sorry, I double checked and found it is also a page from the extension Git repository list.

Comment: maybe it can be configured somewhere?

Comment: You can only see this page after installing the Git repository list extension. I didn't notice this extension had this page before. I suddenly saw this page today and remembered your question. But later I realized that this page is not the official one by default.